# get a User from a table with owner_id

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing a snippet in PHP that get all images from a table "pic" with 3 columns :

1. id
2. owner_id
3. name

So I wrote this :

```
try
{
    $db = new PDO($DB_DSN, $DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // to get an exception when caught an error :)
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Erreur !: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}

$find_pic = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM camagru_jgengo.pic ORDER BY id DESC");
$find_pic->execute();
$pics = $find_pic->fetchAll();
```

And I made a while to show all images from my database.
But I've got a problem, under the image I would like to show the username of the guy who sent the image.

And I've a table 'user' with columns : id and login.

I would like my script to make an array with key (id) => (login).
But I tried a lots of things, I don't succeed to build it.
Or if you have a better idea I'm all open :)

Thank you

Comment: is the owner_id field inside of "pic" table a foreign key to the user table?

Comment: _"But I tried a lots of things"_ - Start by showing us those attempts. Then you should clarify your question a bit. The problem you describe in the text (getting the username) is not the same as in the title (getting images based on owner_id).. which is it? Both? The last sentence is also very unclear (make an array with key (id) => (login)). What do you mean by that? Please show us an example of the expected output.

Comment: I did not use foreign key because I don't know how it works :

I already tried it :

$find_user = $db->prepare("SELECT id, login FROM camagru_jgengo.user");
$find_user->execute();
$users = $find_user->fetchAll();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`join`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) and you can get all information you want with one query. Roughly:

```
SELECT p.*, u.name 
FROM camagru_jgengo.pic as p
join users as u on u.id = p.ownerid
ORDER BY p.id DESC
```

You'll need to modify the columns to match your actual column/table names. If a picture can be uploaded without an owner you might need to make this a `left` join.

Comment: @K.Tromp http://celebnmovies247.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/speedy-gonzales-2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I think what need is a JOIN statement, try google for left join, outer join, inner join, right join, otherwise you could do a while loop for images and inside that a select query to fetch the user data.